# Custom Maven Plugin that will fail an install or deploy

Tags: maven, plugins, deployment

I have written a custom maven plugin that uses svnkit to detect if there are local changes not committed or if your working copy is out of sync with the svn repo, and then fail a mvn deploy.

Here is the execute code:

```
public void execute() throws MojoExecutionException, MojoFailureException {

    PluginDescriptor pd = (PluginDescriptor)getPluginContext().get("pluginDescriptor");
    MavenProject p = (MavenProject)getPluginContext().get("project");

    //init log
    Log log = getLog();
    SVNHelper.initLogger(log);

    //Throws MojoFailureException if there are uncommitted changes
    checkForUncomittedChanges(p.getBasedir(), log);

    //Throws MojoFailureException if the working copy is not up to date
    checkForWorkingCopyUpToDate(p.getBasedir(), log);
}
```

Then in the pom.xml where the plugin used I have it bound to the deploy

The plugin is being called correctly but the build fails after the deploy has already happened. I could move the plugin to be executed on the install phase but I don't want install to show an build failure in this case, I only want deploy to be stopped.

Is there something I am missing.

Comment: You know of the maven-release-plugin ? prepare goal ?

Comment: I want Engineers to be able to deploy SNAPSHOTS to the repo, but not deploy SNAPSHOTS that have uncommitted code or out of date code.  How does the release plugin help with that?

Comment: Use a CI tools like jenkins to deploy the SNAPSHOTs after every commit. That's the simplest solution.

Answer (score 0):

Two suggestions for you:

1. (the way we do it) Use Jenkins for builds after SVN checking and configure Nexus security to *only* let deployments happen from the Jenkins user. This approach requires no custom plugin (which could be removed by the user from the pom.xml).
2. Modify the default lifecycle.

What I'm guessing you've probably done is just configure the Mojo with @phase to make it trigger during the deploy phase. Ensure that the two goals for your deploy phase (deploy:deploy & your:goal) are defined in the same place and then the execution order will be determinate.

To do this, you would need to define a custom lifecycle (http://www.sonatype.com/books/mvnref-book/reference/writing-plugins-sect-plugins-lifecycle.html) and specify the two goals under . Having never done this, I don't know whether you can simply override the default/jar lifecycle or if you'd have to create your own new packaging type.

If in doubt, seriously consider suggestion 1.